# pass query string to url in react-router after trigger event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm starting to build my app. Standing in the Pagination feature.

Base URL: `localhost:3000/discover/movie`

Now when I trying to trigger some event like next button, sort item in drop-down select, year dropdown select. The URL after should be like this:

`localhost:3000/discover/movie?page=1&language=en-US&primary_release_year=1990&sort_by=popularity.asc`

My source code:

nextPage method:

```
nextPage = () => {
    const page = this.state.data.page + 1;
    const year = this.state.selectedYear;
    requestApi.fetchDataDiscoverPagePaginate('discover/movie', page, 'movie', year).then(response => {
        this.setState({data: response.data});
    });
};
```

Sort item by year method:

```
selectYearHandleChange = (selectedYear) => {
    if (selectedYear) {
        let year = selectedYear.value.toString().toLowerCase();
        requestApi.filterData('discover/movie', year).then(response => {
            this.props.listMoviesByYear(response.data);
            this.setState({selectedYear: year});
            this.props.selectedYear(year);
        });
    }
};
```

How can we do that? Please give me some way to solve this problem. Tks

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.history.replace('/chat?id=123')
```

Use history.replace() method could change URL